# display images based on browser width

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have bunch of images that I would like to display using jquery. I have divs and I used jquery to populate the divs based on some node_id criteria. For example, if the node_id is teamA, I display images that has teamA text in the name of the images.

It works find, the problem is that when Put the images on the body of the html, images are displayed vertically until there is no space on the main page.

What I would like to do this depending on the size of the browser window, display the images depending on the size of the browser window. For example, if the image size is 500x500 and the browser window width is 700, I should be able to display one image per line. If the width of the browser is 1200, there should be 2 images per line in my browser window.

To give you an idea, I've put html and jquery code to show you what I am doing:

```
<div class="tab-content" id="tabs1">
    <div id="team_A" class="team"></div>
    <div id="team_B" class="team"></div>
    <div id="team_C" class="team"></div>
    <div id="team_D" class="team"></div>
</div>
```

This is the jquery code to display the image based on jstree node_id:

```
var team_A_Img = "http://test.net" + node_id + "-team_A.png";
            $(function () {

                var myImage = new Image();
                $(myImage).load(function () {

                    $("#team_A").html(myImage);

                }).error(function () {

                    $('#team_A').hide();
                }).attr('src', Img_A_Img)

            });
```

This workds but I need to show the images based on the browser window size either vertically or horizonally, based on how much space I have on the browser. Can somebody give me ideas how I would do this?

Comment: Have you looked into media quires?

Comment: @Eric Lemos, what is media quires?

Comment: In your design, can you specify the width of the image, for example, 500px like you said?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Comment: You don't need to use media queries, just set the div's to `.team { float: left; }` and they will automatically do what you want them to.

Comment: @Andy Right, I read the question wrong, I though he needed the image to span the full width too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can specify the width of the images, you can float them in a block-level element.
For example:

```
<div class="tab-content" id="tabs1">
    <div id="team_A" class="team"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
    <div id="team_B" class="team"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
    <div id="team_C" class="team"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
    <div id="team_D" class="team"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
</div>
```

and use the following CSS:

```
.tab-content {
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow: auto;
}
.team {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
.team img {
    display: block;
}
```

To make this work, set `overflow: auto` in the parent container especially if you want to use a background color or image.

You can adjust the margin or padding of the floated element to create and style gutters between images.

Finally, I use `display: block` on the images to deal with any white space that may result from an inline element.

For reference, see: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/8FEeM/

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="tab-content" id="tabs1">
<div id="team_A" class="team">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.team img{float: left;}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my script can do this:

$('.team').css({ "width": $(window).width(), "height": "auto" });