# Alignment of Images (2 across and 4 down)

Tags: html, css

What is the proper way to align images in a div. I want it to be two across and four down with about 10px separation in between (vertical and horizontal).

Thank you!

Comment: This question is really vague. What kind of alignment (left, right, middle)? Are there any size constraints on the images/container?

Comment: Look at some of the previous answers such as:  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15391116/display-images-based-on-browser-width

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Jolora/cZGfb/

```
div {
    width: 210px;
}

div img {
    float:left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

div img:nth-child(2n) {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

The nth-child selector will not always work in older browsers. For backwards support you should apply a class to the images in the right column and then add that to the selector. For example:

```
div img:nth-child(2n), div img.yourClass {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```