# Please help cant center div in css, need assistance

Tags: css, html, center

I have exported div tags from photoshop design into dreamweaver using slices, extracted the css from head and created a style sheet. all the div tags in the page have an absolute position set for each of them.  I have tried everything i can think of to center all the content on the page and nothing has worked. can someone please take a look at the code and tell me what i am missing.

```
<HTML>


<html>

<head>

<title>Packet Access</title>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<link href="css/style_sheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


</head>
<body style="background-color:#FFFFFF; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; 
margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px`enter code here`;">
<div id="Table_01">
<div id="topper">
</div>
<div id="Topper-2">
</div>
<div id="search">
    <img src="images/search.png" width="133" height="19" alt="">
</div>
<div id="topper-side2"></div>
<div id="topper-side"></div>
<div id="Logo">
    <img src="images/Logo.png" width="254" height="37" alt="">
</div>
<div id="side-logo-right"></div>
<div id="under-search"></div>
<div id="index-09"></div>
<div id="navigation">
    <img src="images/navigation.png" width="457" height="20" alt="">
</div>
<div id="under-logo"></div>
<div id="under-navigation"></div>
<div id="divider">
    <img src="images/divider.jpg" width="1024" height="3" alt="">
</div>
<div id="bg-left">
    <img src="images/bg_left.jpg" width="131" height="147" alt="">
</div>
<div id="index-15">
    <img src="images/index_15.png" width="764" height="52" alt="">
</div>
<div id="bg-right">
    <img src="images/bg_right.jpg" width="129" height="147" alt="">
</div>
<div id="index-17">
    <img src="images/index_17.jpg" width="764" height="243" alt="">
</div>
<div id="index-18">
    <img src="images/index_18.jpg" width="130" height="519" alt="">
</div>
<div id="index-19">
    <img src="images/index_19.jpg" width="1" height="148" alt="">
</div>
<div id="index-20">
    <img src="images/index_20.jpg" width="1" height="148" alt="">
</div>
<div id="index-21">
    <img src="images/index_21.jpg" width="128" height="519" alt="">
</div>
<div id="index-22">
    <img src="images/index_22.png" width="766" height="43" alt="">
</div>
<div id="index-23">
    <img src="images/index_23.png" width="12" height="1" alt="">
</div>
<div id="OTT-box">
    <img src="images/OTT_box.jpg" width="242" height="99" alt="">
</div>
<div id="index-25">
    <img src="images/index_25.png" width="9" height="1" alt="">
</div>
<div id="XFP">
    <img src="images/XFP.jpg" width="242" height="99" alt="">
</div>
<div id="index-27">
    <img src="images/index_27.png" width="10" height="1" alt="">
</div>
<div id="Cache">
    <img src="images/Cache.jpg" width="242" height="99" alt="">
</div>
<div id="index-29">
    <img src="images/index_29.png" width="9" height="1" alt="">
</div>
<div id="index-30">
    <img src="images/index_30.jpg" width="12" height="327" alt="">
</div>
<div id="index-31">
    <img src="images/index_31.jpg" width="9" height="327" alt="">
</div>
<div id="index-32">
    <img src="images/index_32.jpg" width="10" height="327" alt="">
</div>
<div id="index-33">
    <img src="images/index_33.jpg" width="9" height="327" alt="">
</div>
<div id="index-34">
    <img src="images/index_34.png" width="242" height="81" alt="">
</div>
<div id="index-35">
    <img src="images/index_35.png" width="242" height="81" alt="">
</div>
<div id="index-36">
    <img src="images/index_36.png" width="242" height="81" alt="">
</div>
<div id="index-37">
    <img src="images/index_37.jpg" width="242" height="148" alt="">
</div>
<div id="index-38">
    <img src="images/index_38.jpg" width="242" height="148" alt="">
</div>
<div id="index-39">
    <img src="images/index_39.jpg" width="242" height="148" alt="">
</div>
<div id="footer">Copyright © 2012 Packet Access</div>
</div>
<!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
</body>
</html>



<!--The CSS is below-->

<CSS>


@charset "utf-8";


*{  
   margin:0;  
   padding:0;  

}  




.body {
background-color: #000;
text-align:center; /*For IE6 Shenanigans*/

}


#Table_01 {
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
width: 1024px;

}


#topper {
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:0px;
width:1024px;
height:10px;
background-color:#000000;

}


#Topper-2 {
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:10px;
width:763px;
height:6px;
background-color:#000000;

}


#search {
position:absolute;
left:763px;
top:10px;
width:133px;
height:19px;
background-color:#000000;

}


#topper-side2 {
position:absolute;
left:896px;
top:10px;
width:128px;
height:59px;
background-color:#000000;

}


#topper-side {
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:16px;
width:130px;
height:53px;
background-color:#000000;

}


#Logo {
position:absolute;
left:130px;
top:16px;
width:254px;
height:37px;

}


#side-logo-right {
position:absolute;
left:384px;
top:16px;
width:379px;
height:26px;
background-color:#000000;

}


#under-search {
position:absolute;
left:763px;
top:29px;
width:133px;
height:13px;
background-color:#000000;

}


#index-09 {
position: absolute;
left: 384px;
top: 42px;
width: 55px;
height: 27px;
background-color: #000;

}


#navigation {
position:absolute;
left:439px;
top:42px;
width:457px;
height:20px;
background-color:#000000;

}


#under-logo {
position:absolute;
left:130px;
top:53px;
width:254px;
height:16px;
background-color:#000000;

}


#under-navigation {
position:absolute;
left:439px;
top:62px;
width:457px;
height:7px;
background-color:#000000;

}


#divider {
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:69px;
width:1024px;
height:3px;
background-color:#000000;

}



#bg-left {
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:72px;
width:131px;
height:147px;

}


#index-15 {
position:absolute;
left:131px;
top:72px;
width:764px;
height:52px;

}


#bg-right {
position:absolute;
left:895px;
top:72px;
width:129px;
height:147px;

}


#index-17 {
position:absolute;
left:131px;
top:124px;
width:764px;
height:243px;

}


#index-18 {
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:219px;
width:130px;
height:519px;

}


#index-19 {
position:absolute;
left:130px;
top:219px;
width:1px;
height:148px;

}


#index-20 {
position:absolute;
left:895px;
top:219px;
width:1px;
height:148px;

}


#index-21 {
position:absolute;
left:896px;
top:219px;
width:128px;
height:519px;

}


#index-22 {
position:absolute;
left:130px;
top:367px;
width:766px;
height:43px;

}


#index-23 {
position:absolute;
left:130px;
top:410px;
width:12px;
height:1px;

}


#OTT-box {
position:absolute;
left:142px;
top:410px;
width:242px;
height:99px;

}


#index-25 {
position:absolute;
left:384px;
top:410px;
width:9px;
height:1px;

}


#XFP {
position:absolute;
left:393px;
top:410px;
width:242px;
height:99px;

}


#index-27 {
position:absolute;
left:635px;
top:410px;
width:10px;
height:1px;

}


#Cache {
position:absolute;
left:645px;
top:410px;
width:242px;
height:99px;

}


#index-29 {
position:absolute;
left:887px;
top:410px;
width:9px;
height:1px;

}


#index-30 {
position:absolute;
left:130px;
top:411px;
width:12px;
height:327px;

}


#index-31 {
position:absolute;
left:384px;
top:411px;
width:9px;
height:327px;

}


#index-32 {
position:absolute;
left:635px;
top:411px;
width:10px;
height:327px;

}


#index-33 {
position:absolute;
left:887px;
top:411px;
width:9px;
height:327px;

}


#index-34 {
position:absolute;
left:142px;
top:509px;
width:242px;
height:81px;

}


#index-35 {
position:absolute;
left:393px;
top:509px;
width:242px;
height:81px;

}


#index-36 {
position:absolute;
left:645px;
top:509px;
width:242px;
height:81px;

}


#index-37 {
position:absolute;
left:142px;
top:590px;
width:242px;
height:148px;




#index-38 {
position:absolute;
left:393px;
top:590px;
width:242px;
height:148px;

}


#index-39 {
position:absolute;
left:645px;
top:590px;
width:242px;
height:148px;

}


#footer {
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 738px;
width: 100%;
height: 21px;
background-color: #000000;
font-family: "Helvetica LT Std";
font-size: 14px;
color: #999;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 3px;
padding-bottom: 2px;

}



</style>
```

Comment: please post only the relevant code

Comment: Try looking at the previously posted solution to a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15391116/display-images-based-on-browser-width

Comment: It is complete website. You should have given the website link instead. Just joking. Explain what is the problem and where is it? Instead of handing over whole website in our hands and let try our assumptions.

Comment: which div are you trying to center?

Comment: I am trying to center the entire page.  i have tried wrapping everything into another Div and no luck..  I am sorry i added the entire code here but i feel like there is something escaping me and figured it might help if you see the entire picture.

Comment: If i wanted to say expand the entire page to fit the whole width of the page how would i go about doing that?   I changed the width: 1024px to width: 100% and it just remained 1024px and aligned to the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the immediate question of how to center everything on the page, change `#Table_01` from:

```
#Table_01 {
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
width: 1024px;
}
```

to:

```
#Table_01 {
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
width: 1024px;
position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Ahhh Tim thank you so much..   i am unsure how i missed that one. im sure i changed all the position tags to relative and things got wacky in the page.  I exported the div's from photoshop design when i should have just started fresh.

Comment: your comment.. answering the emidiate question!!   are you implying that there are other issues here?  i would love the feedback.

Comment: question,  I have centered the div and everything looks great.  is there a way i can make the entire portion of the page that is not included in my centered div have a black background?  I tried
    #body {
    background-color: #000000;
    }

Comment: Lots of tiny, absolutely positioned slices will be an absolute nightmare to maintain.

Comment: how would you recommend i alleviate that nightmare?

Comment: Tim:  i guess i could now go and remove all the unused slices. which are alot of them..  and that should clean up alot of it.  is there a way that i could use css to stretch the side div's to fit the width of the page is 1024px didnt fill it?